# Why on a single variable I need to specify the memory address while on array I don't need it?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, declaration, memory-address

Simple [example](http://cpp.sh/8uljj):

```
double array[] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
double *p1 = array;
printf("p1: %f\n", *(p1));

int x = 2;
int* p2 = &x;
printf("p2: %d\n", *p2);
```

why on p1 I need to use & and on array I don't need this in c/c++? Is there a logic reason?

Comment: Because an array is an address/pointer?

Comment: @FirstStep: No, an array is *not* an address. An array expression is implicitly converted to the address of its 0th element in most contexts.

Comment: @keithThompson ahh.. I almost got it

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/241631).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think that array evaluates to a variable of type 'address' while x is a variable of type int. x is stored in a memory location and &x gives you the address of that memory location.

The address of the array, that is &array will evaluate to the address of the first element and hence the address of the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

An array designator in expressions is converted (with rare exception) to pointer to its first element.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

And from the C++ Standard (4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion)

> 1 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown
>   bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The
>   result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Thus this declaration

```
double *p1 = array;
```

is equivalent to

```
double *p1 = &array[0];
            ^^^
```

Consider this demonstrative program

```
$include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double array[] = { 1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0 };

    std::cout << "sizeof( array ) = " << sizeof( array ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof( array + 0 ) = " << sizeof( array + 0 ) << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( array ) = 40
sizeof( array + 0 ) = 8
```

In the first output statement the array designator is used as an operand of the `sizeof` operator. So there is no conversion from the type `double[5]` to `double *`.

In the second output statement the array designator is used in expression `array + 0` that in turn is used as an operand of the `sizeof` operator. 
In this case there is conversion from the type `double[5]` to the type `double *`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bjarne Stroustrup's book - [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) name of an array refers to all elemnts of the array, so for example:

```
char ar[10];
sizeof(ar) // 10
```

> However, the name of an array turns into ("decays to") a pointer with
>   the slightest excuse.

So this is why we can have: `char* c = ar`. Now `c` is initialized to `&c[0]` (that is first element of an array) making `sizeof(c)` 4 (depending of implementation.

As for variable it is just one element.

Comment: This mistake is so common that even c++ teacher's propagate it, do not do it. Array is not a pointer. Period.

Comment: @Slava I have added reference for my answer - I hope now it's clear

Answer (score 0):

Because an array decays to a pointer of it's declared type that points to the first element that the array holds.